# jQuery Pagination plugin scroll to next 5 pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, pagination

I'm using http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/ version v1.4.1, I want to add a next button just like 'first' and 'last' button on which when user click should display next 5 pages. Currently when i click on next button only one page increment took place. Following is my code:

```
            $('#itemSearchPage-top,#itemSearchPage-bottom').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: <?php echo $recordPages ?>,
            visiblePages: 5,
            startPage: <?php echo $itemSearchPageNo ?>,
            href: false,
            first: '',
            prev: '<',
            next: '>',
            last: '',
            onPageClick: function (evt, page) {
                itemSearchMain(page);
            }
        });
```

for example let say there are total 15 pages and when page load pagination display  <<,<1,2,3,4,5,>,>>.. When user click on '>>' pagination should display
<<,<,6,7,8,9,10,>,>>

Comment: you mean to say that the five pages should be hiddenly paginated and there must be only first and the last button?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj I've updated question, please check. Thanks!

Comment: how many pages you have currently there I have checked in my localhost with 30 pages and it's working fine like you want to make sure your page's total is something like 15 or above.